# Did you both get (yourself or yourselves) some ice cream?

Tags: reflexive-pronouns

Which is correct?

> Did you both get (yourself or yourselves) some ice cream?

---

Note: This is from an English exercise. You can see the whole worksheet scanned [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGMZl.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

Since the sentence is talking about two people (*you both*) which is more than one, it definitely should be *yourselves* which is the plural version of the reflexive pronoun *yourself*:

> Did you both get **yourselves** some ice cream?

Comment: That's what I thought. And said. but aparently the kids teacher doesn't agree.. I said since it has a plural context the selection is going to be plural.

Comment: @Josh I don't know why she says that. What are her arguments?

Comment: @Josh I agree that “you” is plural — second person plural— even without **both** in the sentence.  It could only be singular (“yourself”) if it were re-written: “did you **each** get yourself some ice cream?“